# Are these MOSFETs wired correctly?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, mosfet, esp32

I have an ESP32 that I'm trying to use to control a motor and a water-level sensor. Both of these devices are 12 V DC, so I'm using a DC-DC converter that takes 12 V input and outputs both 5 V and 12 V. The 5 V powers the ESP32 while the 12 V supplies the devices.

The devices are power gated with P30N06LE MOSFETs, and these are activated via GPIO pins on the ESP32.

The problem is that I am only getting readings from the water-level sensor when the DC motor is powered.

The circuit diagram doesn't show the two momentary push buttons wired to other GPIO pins. When the first of these is pushed the embedded code sets the motor MOSFET gate to HIGH, thereby powering the motor. When the second button is pushed the water-level MOSFET gate is set HIGH, thereby powering the water-level sensor. Each MOSFET is set LOW when the relevant button is released.

The `loop()` code looks to see if the push button associated with the water-level sensor is HIGH, and if so takes an `AnalogRead()` of the sensor wire connected at A2, and sets a globally scoped `int` variable, `WATER_LEVEL_VALUE`, to that value, e.g. `WATER_LEVEL_VALUE = AnalogRead(WATER_LEVEL_SENSOR);`.

When the push button associated with the motor MOSFET is pressed, the motor powers up as expected, then stops when the button is released.

When the push button associated with the water-level MOSFET is pressed, `WATER_LEVEL_VALUE` remains at zero.

I have tried making the `AnalogRead()` run if EITHER switch is pressed, and I do get a value in `WATER_LEVEL_VALUE` when the motor MOSFET is activated, which is not ideal, because the two devices need to operate independently.

It seems like I might have a wiring problem, because the water-level sensor should not be powered by the motor MOSFET being activated.

Some assumptions about the diagram. I was limited by parts in Fritzing, so:

- I'm using an ESP32 S2 Saola, not the pictured Nano
- The DC-DC converter I'm using has separate output for 5 V and 12 V. I have used the NC connectors in the circuit to depict 5 V. I have added another image of the actual converter that I'm using.

[image: circuit diagram]

[image: 5A 350KHz 25V Buck DC to DC Converter (DFRobot DFR0205)]

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic using the built in function here on EE.SE. Click on edit and then the schematic symbol. Draw your schematic and press insert.

Comment: tangential: you are missing a reverse polarity diode in parallel with the motor, which prevents the motor from possibly damaging the MOSFET when it turns off. Keyword: "freewheeling diode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is the supply switch of the water-level sensor. You can turn off the sensor by disconnecting GND of the sensor as your circuit shows. But if you do so, the positive supply is still present at the sensor and an unknown current flows from there to the analog input of the MCU. This can, or already has destroyed the analog input.

You must disconnect the positive supply contact of the sensor in such a circuit. This can, for example, be achieved with an extra P MOSFET.

Another problem is, that GND of the MCU must be connected to GND of the 12 V side. The output and input signals of the MCU are relative to GND and this reference must be present at sensors and loads. Probably this is only an error in the schematic, I cant't say.

Connect a capacitor (1 uF) parallel to the motor to suppress high frequency interferences of the motor brushes.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, @Jens! This makes sense, I think. I'm just unclear on the schematic for a second (third actually) mosfet. Would this require yet another GPIO pin to control? 

That's a valid concern about frying the sensor, but the bench supply indicates only very small fluctuations in current across the various states, and I have been getting accurate readings when the motor is engaged. I've been lucky, it would seem, but it's a good lesson learned, so thanks!

Comment: The MCU and 12V grounds are definitely connected. You guessed correctly, it is an error in this schematic only.

Comment: The ground might be connected on the power module.